# Why can't I access this field in an interface?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand interfaces better and am not understanding why `s` has no field `Width`. My [example is here](http://play.golang.org/p/bVjlY9hfu2):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type shapes interface {
    setWidth(float64)
}

type rect struct {
    Width float64
}

func (r *rect) setWidth(w float64) {
    r.Width = w
}

var allShapes = map[string]shapes{
    "rect": &rect{},
}

func main() {
    r := &rect{}
    r.setWidth(5)
    fmt.Println(r.Width)  // this works
    for _, s := range allShapes {
        s.setWidth(7)
        fmt.Println(s.Width) // why not???
    }
}
```

Why does `r` have Width but `s` doesn't? The exact error I get is:

```
s.Width undefined (type shapes has no field or method Width)
```

Comment: Off-topic: A good style is to use singular form for class/struct names until it's a set/collection. So in your case a `shape` instead of the `shapes` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shapes` interface is what `*rect` implements, but it is not a concrete type `*rect`. It is, like any interface, a set of methods allowing any type satisfying it to pass, like giving a temporary visitor sticker to it to go up the building.

For instance, if there is a monkey (or for what it's worth, a dolphin) who can act and do everything a human can, in Go's building, he can pass the guard and go up the elevator. However, that doesn't make him genetically human.

Go is statically-typed, meaning even two types with the same underlying type cannot be dynamically converted or coerced to one another without a type assertion or consciously converting the type.

```
var a int
type myInt int
var b myInt

a = 2
b = 3
b = a         // Error! cannot use a (type int) as type myInt in assignment.
b = myInt(a)  // This is ok.
```

Imagine with me for a second this situation:

```
type MyInt int
type YourInt int

type EveryInt interface {
        addableByInt(a int) bool
}

func (i MyInt) addableByInt(a int) bool {
    // whatever logic doesn't matter
    return true
}


func (i YourInt) addableByInt(a int) bool {
    // whatever logic doesn't matter
    return true
}

func main() {
    // Two guys want to pass as an int
    b := MyInt(7)
    c := YourInt(2)

    // Do everything an `EveryInt` requires
    // and disguise as one 
    bi := EveryInt(b)
    ci := EveryInt(c)

    // Hey, look we're the same! That's the closest
    // we can get to being an int!
    bi = ci          // This is ok, we are EveryInt brotherhood
    fmt.Println(bi)  // bi is now 2

    // Now a real int comes along saying
    // "Hey, you two look like one of us!"
    var i int
    i = bi           // Oops! bi has been made

    // ci runs away at this point

}
```

Now back to your scenerio--imagine a `*circle` comes along implementing `shapes`:

```
type circle struct {
        Radius float64
}

func (c *circle) setWidth(w float64) {
        c.Radius = w
}
```

`*circle` is totally passable as `shapes` but it does not have `Width` property because it is not a `*rect`. An interface cannot access an underlying type's property directly, but can only do so through implemented method set. In order to access a property, a **type assertion** is need on the interface so that instance becomes a concrete type:

```
var r *rect

// Verify `s` is in fact a `*rect` under the hood
if r, ok := s.(*rect); ok {
        fmt.Println(r.Width)
}
```

This is at the core of why a statically-typed language like Go is always faster than dynamically-typed counterparts, which will almost always use some kind of reflection to handle type coercion dynamically for you.

Comment: Why can I access r.Width, then?

Comment: @kristen because `r` is already a concrete type (namely `*rect`). Go has a static type, meaning even two types which share a same underlying type cannot be converted or coerced to one another without type assertion or us consciously defining the correct type. Interfaces are not a concrete type. It's a set of methods which simply says "if this one can do all these, she go anywhere this type can" but it doesn't make her become the type until you "ask for her id" (aka type assert).

Answer (score 3):

s is a an implementer of the shapes interface, but in the for loop not typed as a rect.
If you do a type assertion to force s be of the concrete type like so:

```
s.(*rect).Width
```

You will get what you want.

You need to be careful about mixing concrete types and interfaces like that though.

Comment: Can you elaborate "You need to be careful about mixing concrete types and interfaces like that though."? Is there a better way to do it, then?

Comment: In your example for instance, why can you assume that this particular element of  `map[string]shapes` is a `*rect`.  Should you have another function in the interface that exposes what you need? What should you do if you have some other implementation (like pie-o-pah's circle)?